# Can I filter my favorites by tags?

Tags: feature-request, support

Can I do it? If not, can it be a feature request?

Comment: Perhaps a text-box atop the favs list, where you type in tags that can autocomplete (like when you're posting a question) then the tag appears in a horiz. list of tags next to the text-box, and this filters your favorites by that tag. Adding another tag would further narrow the list.

Comment: I can't upvote, so I'll just say this would be a great feature. I'd be happy with a collection of tag buttons to click at the top of the fav's list.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the infavorites is [no longer supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78946/reimplement-the-broken-searching-within-favorites-functionality) since the new search was introduced early 2011. (Just in case anyone like me arrives here and attempts to use the `infavorites:mine` syntax.)

Answer (score 2):

Search for:

```
infavorites:mine [tag]
```

Comment: Aww, how did I click on a question that's been around for an hour and find that you beat me to the answer by less than a minute :(

Comment: The `infavorites` is [no longer supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76449/new-meta-search-engine-help-us-test) when the new search is introduced early 2011.

Comment: Brilliant! But how am I going find this answer again when I can't remember the search syntax?

Comment: doh - didn't read the comment above. Should really be an answer