# Reimplement the broken searching within favorites functionality

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, search, bookmarks

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-favorited-question) there was a mechanism implemented to allow searching within sets of favorite questions, most usefully used when searching through your own favorite list (which for some users can be rather large):

`infavorite:mine [searchterm]`

According to the most recent comments on that [same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-favorited-question), this feature got "broken" sometime in early 2011.  Certainly, in trying to use this functionality myself, it does not appear to be working any more.  I'm assuming this happened when the complete search engine was modified, as advertised in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/).

A simple enough request:  Can we please have our favorite search back?

Comment: It wasn't so much "broken" as it was deprecated. [The original Meta post for the new search system was deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76449/new-meta-search-engine-help-us-test), but to quote it: "`infavorites:` is...no more, this would be terribly expensive on the back-end and just wasn't used enough to keep it around". I didn't have a long list of favorites myself, but I've heard of others who have found it useful.

Comment: Oh no! This is gone? This was so incredibly useful. Is it feasible to fall back to a LIKE query against SQL Server just for the favorite searches? I'd be happy to sacrifice a bit of quality in the results just for the ability to search in my favorites at all.

Comment: I am making this question a favorite.  Hopefully I'll be able to locate it in the future.

Comment: This has [been fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161743/1438).  (Ping @Nick Craver).

Comment: perhaps [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176861/303080) is a better accepted answer now? Unfortunately sorting answers here by *active, oldest,* or *votes* all show the currently accepted but inaccurate "This was dropped... `status-deferred`" answer at the top.

Comment: As the original question asker, I've changed the accepted answer on this question.  At the time of asking the question,  Nick Craver's answer was both correct and the most informative as the searching within favourites _was_ broken, however now, the searching within favourites is back and so Lake's answer is now the most informative and correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) (Dec '12) states **the `infavorites:mine` functionality has returned** ([referenced in this answer as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161743/219071)).

This question already has the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag, but I'm adding this for reference as I didn't find it immediately myself.

Comment: Good catch - but also flag the main post and let mods know to mark it as [tag:status-completed]

Comment: It works, yay! *This is the correct answer now*

Answer (score 12):

This was dropped as infeasible due to performance concerns.  When you're inside SQL joining to a table to filter results is a perfectly valid option, and one a relational database is *designed* to do, and do well.

However, once you leave that [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) world (as we've done with the search overhaul - search is now handled by [Lucene](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/), not SQL/Full Text), joining back to that list of favorites (which varies in length *widely*) as a list questions to search becomes a much uglier task in terms of performance.  Lucene is designed to search based on attributes in the documents it has, rather than a list of post Ids against a known list (which would be quite a large boolean query to run underneath - directly proportional to the number of favorites that user has).

For the users who would *want* to search in their favorites (the same group likely to have many), that's where it's most difficult to do this efficiently, and what's why the option was removed.  That's not to say we won't bring this back, if we can do it in a way that performs well - even with a high number of favorites, we will.

I'm making this [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now, it is on my todo though.

Comment: Thanks very much for this reply, Nick, and your detailed reasoning as to why it was removed.  I appreciate it.  I would still definitely love it see the search of favorites back in one form or another as I do believe it is a very handy feature to have and goes towards the overall mantra of the site - to make quality information accessible and available - especially for those of us who have "bookmarked" many great Q&A's over time.

Comment: You guys didn't remove the 'favorites' tab in the profile page, so that part must not be the bottleneck. I'd be pretty happy if I could just get an entire page of those favorites and do a browser `find` on the titles. Can't we at least have that?

Comment: Can't you just query both Lucene and SQL Server, then use C# to return the intersection of those two queries?

Comment: is there any current workaround to this? I.e. What method would you recommend a user to use when he wants to search a string within his favorites?

Comment: @AmV - Unfortunately, there isn't currently a work-around, it's something we may circle back to when we give favorites more love.

Comment: If it is hard on the server side, then why don't you implement a simple filter in the frontend? You do already a query for "mine" favorites. Why does the deferral take sooooo long? Doesn't it have enough user votes? Hint: there are several questions around the subject and all of them have 50+ votes.

Comment: @Rajish - If it was a client-side filter you'd just have a lot of empty search pages in most cases.  And the votes for something does make us take a look at it, but they don't make it any more technically feasible to accomplish.

Comment: Just to be more clear what I mean by frontend filter is something like scaladoc javascript filter of the hits already queried and downloaded. Here is the idea I'm writing about: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option - there are two input boxes: writing a string in it filters the list.

Comment: @Rajish - I'm saying the likelihood of matches in your 15-50 results is low, so many would inexplicably see an empty page.

Comment: this seems to be no longer accurate

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't seem like it should be that hard to accomplish. Just do the Lucene query to get the list of post IDs that match, query the SQL Server for the specified favorite post IDs, and use the intersection of those as the search results.

Based on my *zero* knowledge of how the system works in real life, I would expect this feature to be trivial to implement with a few lines of LINQ.

Comment: +1 (^[_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78946/reimplement-the-broken-searching-within-favorites-functionality/84149#84149)^)