# Change "user:me" search feature to search all questions I participated in, not only my own posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

Here's the problem I ran into.  Today, I was looking for an answer that I wrote a while ago.  I knew it had to do with determining the absolute base path of the request in PHP.  I also knew it had `absolute` in the title.  So I entered `user:me absolute` in the search bar.  All of my results were either not what I was looking for, or used absolute in another context.

I finally found the answer, and it was this question: [Best method for creating absolute path in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893088/best-method-for-creating-absolute-path-in-php-see-3-methods-listed-inside/2893104#2893104).  So the word I was searching for is right in the title.  But since my post didn't explicitly use the word `Absolute`, it wasn't included in the search results.

So there are 2 possible fixes that I can see:

1. Include the title in answer searches.
2. Include all posts on pages the user has involvement on.

I know this may water down some search results, so perhaps a search modifier would work better...

Comment: Some background on performance: see Nick's answer at [Reimplement the broken searching within favorites functionality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78946/reimplement-the-broken-searching-within-favorites-functionality/79956#79956). That said: if filtering results on favorites is ever implemented, then maybe filtering on author/participant is easier too. (But: I really don't know how `user:me` is currently implemented.)

Comment: If at all doable, this would be great, but I would christen it `with-me`

Comment: @Pekka: I would keep it generic, so `with:` where the following is either `me|userid`...  `with:me` or `with:338665`...

Comment: I'd actually quite like to see answers that were /not/ by me - for instance something like "git bfg -user:me" would exclude answers I'd done, allowing me to see how other people were answering questions on those search terms (unfortunately that query doesn't seem to work like that, still returning results by me)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

Change `user:me` to work as requested here.

Add a new boolean axis `mine`

```
mine:1
mine:0
```

`user:me` would change to posts in which the user participated

`mine:X` would be posts owned by that user.

Comment: Well, what about search other user's exact posts.  perhaps add another general axis `posted:me` (which is who posted the content to be searched).  So `user:me` would be all pages I had activity in (comments|questions|answers), and `posted:me` would be only content that I posted...