# How can I see my favourites marked with a particular tag?

Tags: discussion, support, bookmarks

I want to see a list of my favourites which are marked C or C++. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search in list of favorited questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions)

Answer (score 3):

No, right now you're not able to search within your favorites.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/search-in-list-of-favorited-questions) on it has been [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred).

Comment: For the curious, see [Nick's explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78946/reimplement-the-broken-searching-within-favorites-functionality/79956#79956) of why this would be problematic.