# Categorize Stack Overflow favorite questions

Tags: feature-request, search, user-interface, bookmarks

There is a long list of "Favorite Questions" in my Stack Overflow account. I think there should be some functionality to categorize questions according to their relevance, like:

- JavaScript and its frameworks related questions should be displayed in a category.
- Browser related questions should be displayed in a category.
- Database questions should be displayed in a category.
- *et cetera*

If the list of favorites is too long, I'm not able to access questions quickly anymore. All I need to do is to see each question's tag and find it myself or do a Google search.

Comment: +1, especially since we can't filter searches by favorites anymore! :(    ...   Related: [Can I filter my favorites by tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61148/148310) and also: [Reimplement the broken searching within favorites functionality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78946/148310).

Comment: @Bhupi Do you mean, filtering by tags? Or how would you define "JavaScript and its Frameworks" questions?

Comment: Yes tag related filtering can also do but I think it may be very complex to implement. the other thing can be done like, there should be some functionality to manage one's favorites. One can define categories of his favorite questions, mean it should be completely in control of user s/he should be able to manage his account as s/he likes.

Comment: Hey thanks Cody Gray for editing :)

Comment: I would be happy with an `InFavorites:` option for search.

Comment: Hey Lance Roberts, when I put question title, it didn't show me any question which was related to mine and so I could not able to see that the question for "Favorite improvements" has already been asked by someone else.